# How to plot two graphs side by side using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, pdf, graph, gridextra, par

I am trying to plot 2 plots side by side using gplot2 in R. I want them to be printed both in a png as well as a pdf file. Following is my test dataframe called "data_select":

```
Biomarkers  Age Sex Percentile  Percentiles
GeneX   42.5    men 25  0.028
GeneX   42.5    women   25  0.022
GeneX   47.5    men 25  0.027
GeneX   47.5    women   25  0.023
GeneX   52.5    men 25  0.027
GeneX   52.5    women   25  0.024
GeneX   57.5    men 25  0.029
GeneX   57.5    women   25  0.023
GeneX   62.5    men 25  0.03
GeneX   62.5    women   25  0.024
GeneX   67.5    men 25  0.033
GeneX   67.5    women   25  0.026
GeneX   72.5    men 25  0.028
GeneX   72.5    women   25  0.022
GeneX   42.5    men 50  0.036
GeneX   42.5    women   50  0.03
GeneX   47.5    men 50  0.036
GeneX   47.5    women   50  0.029
GeneX   52.5    men 50  0.035
GeneX   52.5    women   50  0.029
GeneX   57.5    men 50  0.039
GeneX   57.5    women   50  0.031
GeneX   62.5    men 50  0.038
GeneX   62.5    women   50  0.03
GeneX   67.5    men 50  0.04
GeneX   67.5    women   50  0.035
GeneX   72.5    men 50  0.033
GeneX   72.5    women   50  0.032
GeneX   42.5    men 75  0.049
GeneX   42.5    women   75  0.04
GeneX   47.5    men 75  0.049
GeneX   47.5    women   75  0.036
GeneX   52.5    men 75  0.045
GeneX   52.5    women   75  0.038
GeneX   57.5    men 75  0.051
GeneX   57.5    women   75  0.041
GeneX   62.5    men 75  0.047
GeneX   62.5    women   75  0.04
GeneX   67.5    men 75  0.05
GeneX   67.5    women   75  0.043
GeneX   72.5    men 75  0.049
GeneX   72.5    women   75  0.04
```

Here is the code for my two graphs (men and women) that I would like to print side by side.

```
# Load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

# Select for men and women
data_select_men <- data_select[ data_select$Sex %in% "men", ]
data_select_women <- data_select[ data_select$Sex %in% "women", ]

pdf ("graph.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

# Graph for men
check_men <- data_select_men %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = data_select_men$Age,
        y = data_select_men$Percentiles,
        group = data_select_men$Percentile))
check_men <- check_men +
    geom_line(aes(color = data_select_men$Percentile), na.rm = TRUE) +
    geom_point(aes(color = data_select_men$Percentile),
                size = 1,
                na.rm = TRUE) +
    # labs(x = NULL) + 
    labs(title="GeneX (men)", x="Age groups", y="Percentiles") + 

    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5),
        labels = c("40-45", "45-50", "50-55", "55-60", "60-65", "65-70", "70-75")) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0.025, 0.050, 0.075, 0.100),
        labels = c("25", "50", "75", "100"))

# Graph for women
check_women <- data_select_women %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = data_select_women$Age,
        y = data_select_women$Percentiles,
        group = data_select_women$Percentile))
check_women <- check_women +
    geom_line(aes(color = data_select_women$Percentile), na.rm = TRUE) +
    geom_point(aes(color = data_select_women$Percentile),
                size = 1,
                na.rm = TRUE) +
    # labs(x = NULL) + 
    labs(title="GeneX (women)", x="Age groups", y="Percentiles") + 

    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5),
        labels = c("40-45", "45-50", "50-55", "55-60", "60-65", "65-70", "70-75")) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0.025, 0.050, 0.075, 0.100),
        labels = c("25", "50", "75", "100"))

dev.off()
```

Currently what I get from this is one pdf file with 2 pages (1 graph per page). What I want is one pdf file with one page and these 2 graphs side by side.

I have already used "par(mfrow=c(1,2))" as you see, but it is not working. In addition, I also tried using using the package "gridExtra" using the following lines before "dev.off".

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(check_men, check_women, nrow = 1) # I also tried using ncol = 2.
```

But this also did not work. It gives me one pdf file with 3 pages. The first 2 pages contain the correct plots, and the last page contains 2 plots but these 2 plots are blank and does not contain all the attributes.

Can anyone help me with how can I have the exact graphs that I made, but side by side? Thanking you.

Comment: Unrelated but: you should not be using `$` inside of `aes()`. So for example, `aes(x = Age)`, not `aes(x = data_select_women$Age)`.

Comment: I believe you should simply facet (see `help("facet_grid")`  and `help("facet_wrap")`). Your attempt with `grid.arrange` should work but maybe previous tries with `par` (which cannot work) are messing with this.

Comment: Side note: with this code, because `dplyr` already re-exports `magrittr::%>%`, you do not need `library(magrittr)`. The only reason you'd need that is if you need other pipe-like operators that are not re-exported, such as `%T>%`, `%$%`, `%<>%`, or the not-often used (or known) `magrittr::\`n'est pas\`` function (a not-so-shortcut for base's `!`).

Comment: Thank you for the notes all of you. @Roland, I did try this even without the use of par completely, but it still does not work with grid.arrange. I am still trying to figure out how to work this out using the help functions.

Comment: You define `check_women <- ggplot(...)` as a blank plot. You modify it on the next line, adding layers `check_women + geom_line() ...`, but you never save the updates, you never assign them back to `check_women`. It's as if you have `x <- 0`, then run `x + 1`. The result, `1`, prints, but `x` is still 0. If you want to actually modify `x`, you need `x <- x + 1`. It will work for printing that plot fo file (just like `1` prints to the console when you run `x + 1`), but if you use `x` later, it is still 0. When you use `check_women` in `grid.arrange` it is still blank. (Same for `check_men`)

Comment: @Gregor, thanks so much. Yes indeed, this was the problem. I have now done the assinging and have edited my code above. Now, I get one pdf with one page and 2 plots side by side. This works correctly for both plots now!!